# Is there some kind of special scrutiny near 20k?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, post-ban, serial-voting

I started a few weeks ago to have my questions systematically downvoted (last one was a moment ago). It is quite weird because their quality was maybe never stellar (though I always make efforts to build a  nice one) but in any case - why now?

I did not even realize this until a (now deleted) question on SE Meta where my account was specifically discussed as having "a trail of bad quality questions".

I am not interested in fighting the downvotes - everyone is free to do that if they want and my life is not attached to any kind of rep. The thing I do not want, though, is to have my account blocked because of that (it looks like there is a "blocking for continuous bad questions").

The problem is specifically on SO, other sites are fine (sometimes up, sometimes down).

What is the recourse?

Worst case I will leave this account on the side (use it for the other SE) and start a new one but it is really a pity.

Comment: In general, no, but having high rep and asking a lot of questions *will* draw attention, good or bad. should it? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ There's an argument to be made regarding not wasting answerer's time by asking poor questions, and having been around longer you should be asking good questions in general, but at the end of the day the backlash is unwarranted; Your overall contribution has been positive and you're far from a problem. Keep at it IMO, just take the critisizm and learn from it.

Comment: There is no special scrutiny at any rep level. But there is something known as the “meta effect”: when something is brought up on meta, it tends to draw a lot more eyeballs than it otherwise would, and with the eyeballs come the voting fingers (up, down, or otherwise). Re a potential question ban: that’s imposed automatically by a secret-ish algorithm, and is not and cannot be imposed (or lifted) manually by a human. The votes will ultimately determine whether a ban is applied or lifted. But, while I don’t know the secrets of the algorithm, I have to imagine getting a ban at ~20k is hard.

Comment: If you think you are being targeted then raise a mod flag and they will investigate. I don't think you can just be *"blocked for continuous bad questions"* after hundreds of good ones

Comment: Any post on meta will invoke [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). If you think the votes are personal, you can raise a custom flag (usually on any of your own post) and explain your suspicions.

Comment: The short answer is: no, there isn't any particular "graduation" process or anything where you get reviewed more. It would be nice if someone who was about to become a [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) had a solid idea of what makes a good question. Your [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67893218/3001761) lacked a MRE, suggesting you didn't go through basic debugging; did you not wonder if it was specific to "skipping" a stage and try copying into the second one, for example, which would have ruled that out.

Comment: Given your ~700 questions, don't worry, you are not in any danger of getting question-banned. It mostly affects newish users whose average question score is close to neutral or negative (although the exact algorithm is, as you may know, unknown). Starting a new account to avoid the ban is also against the rules last time I checked, so please don't do that. In any case, it happens, and those votes will subside with time.

Comment: *it looks like there is a "blocking for continuous bad questions"* No. Once you're above a certain rep level quality-bans are no longer a thing. You're way above the threshold, not only due to rep but also because **all** your past questions weren't bad enough to receive downvotes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: as for the last one, it is now 4 hours I am intermittently looking at it, copying the stages back and forth. If you look at previous ones, there is an effort to explain the why, how etc. I understand that some are better than others - what really surprised me was that it started early May. I do not care whatever about the rep - rather about leaving a track of useful information (which also means I come back to questions/answers to update them if needed, try to use understandable English (this is not my first or second language). And honestly not even complaining, just curious.

Comment: @DanBron You are exempt from the question ban if you have more than 1500 rep IIRC. So that's not a worry.

Comment: @10Rep Ah, good to know. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: @10Rep I think that's a myth. I recall a Questioned-banned user with around that much reputation. I cannot recall the meta post though.

Comment: @10Rep Agreed with Scratte here - did you mean *effectively* exempt from it due to sheet amount of positive contributions? If there is a post you can reference it would be nice to bookmark, though.

Comment: @WoJ - you also brought up one of your questions on Meta on May 12th, thus exposing it (it got downvotes on May 12th, 14th, and today in correlation to today's post). It shouldn't surprize you - every interaction on Meta has a risk of getting too much attention (wanted or not).

Comment: @OlegValter I don't have a post for reference, but I recall learning that from a user. But you do make a point - a user with 1500 rep is _effectively_ exempt from a question ban because of previous contributions. I think someone would have to screw up really bad to get into a question ban at that point. Edit:  [This comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408255/is-there-some-kind-of-special-scrutiny-near-20k/408261#comment847603_408255) is where I learnt it from.

Comment: @10Rep thank you, I think rene meant just that - effectively above the threshold (although I am notoriously bad at assuming what people mean :))

Comment: You have 13 pages of questions with positive scores and 1 page of questions with a negative score, and your worst-received question has a score of -4. Hardly what I'd call a "string of bad questions."

Comment: Lots of misinformation bandied about here regarding question bans, per usual. There's no specific reputation threshold where question bans don't apply. The way to think about this is that question bans are a *total quality score*. Thus, posting valuable contributions will help you to get out of (or, equally, avoid) a question ban. The posting of valuable contributions is heavily correlated with upvotes and therefore reputation. But there's no specific point at which a question ban becomes not an option. Anecdotally, though, it's very true that users with >1k reputation *rarely* get banned.

Comment: @CodyGray _"There's no specific reputation threshold where question bans don't apply"_ Should we take your word for this? I'm only double-checking because AFAIK mods don't know the exact criteria and because rene [seemed to have a source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408221/user-avoiding-question-ban-somehow#comment847366_408221) on this.

Comment: @41686d6564 That's not a source. That's a single example of someone who someone else thinks is asking low-quality questions but has not yet gotten a question ban. *Way* too many variables there. You're right that moderators don't know the exact criteria, but we've put together many pieces. The correlation between reputation and question bans is more subtle than some kind of rule.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure I understand the first part of your comment. Maybe I should've linked two comments from that post; rene said [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408221/user-avoiding-question-ban-somehow#comment847358_408221), then replied with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408221/user-avoiding-question-ban-somehow#comment847366_408221) when someone asked for more details. If I understand that reply correctly, the source of that information is Shog9 (at least as far as rene remembers).

Comment: I see. I guess I missed the specific comments you were trying to point me to. Well, I don't remember hearing that from Shog, and I can't find a reference to it anywhere. I find quite a few various references to there not being any particular reputation threshold, which matches well with my general understanding of how it works. Shog may well have been simplifying: e.g., someone who has 1500+ rep is exceedingly unlikely to be subject to a question ban because you can't get to 1500+ rep without having a largely positive overall quality score. @41686d6564

Comment: The question would be better if it would quantify the "systematic downvoting" a bit more. Could it still be chance? For making a case of potential voting fraud (targeting users instead of content), there should be a bit more statistics to begin with really.

Comment: @Trilarion: I did not mention (nor really had in mind)  fraud, or emotional downvoting. I was just wondering if there was something special around 20k, and also the "bad questions sequence" ban.

Comment: The details of the question ban algorithm are a secret, so that nobody can exploit it. That means that nobody really will tell you how far away you are from a question ban.  The best advice is probably to assume that if everything was fine so far, it will probably stay like this, don't worry too much but also try to ask the best questions possible.

Comment: It may be that by asking here you may get the special scrutiny. :) I looked over some of your questions (last four pages of questions, random selection) and I could not find anything in particular bad about them. Maybe the recent negative series is just pure bad luck. Some questions could profit from more research, others may be opinionated (when asking about more idomatic ways) and others may be of little general interest (how to format something in a special way). However, they are in general clear, focused and on-topic.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I have rolled back your edit because that exact phrase is quoted in [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408257/11573842)...

Comment: _I am not interested in fighting the downvotes _ => That is fine... but if people say that your account has left a trail of bad quality questions, I'd hope you are interested in _why_ they think so, and _how_ to improve the quality of your questions. If your questions get an occasional downvote here and there, it can be chucked up to fickle users. If your questions _regularly_ attract downvotes, the problem likely lies with your questions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. This would require people to leave a comment when they downvote. This is not the case, it is difficult to be a telepath.

Comment: @WoJ: Urk, I hate it when that happens :( In this case, you may want to take "advice from a friend", if you know someone in the same tag which doesn't suffer from this. For the [tag:rust] there's a chatroom with the usual lurkers, and they're happy to give advice to newcomers -- though they'd have left a comment, too. There may be something similar in the tags you frequent? Asking for a few chat users to double-check your question and make suggestions would be far friendlier than attempting to invoke Meta, and risk the Meta-effect.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you know, SO is for me a source of interesting questions (of others) and a place to ask mine. I truly have zero interest in the rep part, it could not exist and downvotes do not matter, except that they bury the question, and attract more downvotes. This is what I raised the point on meta, specifically about the block. As for asking better questions - I am eager to learn - but

Comment: @MatthieuM. (cont'd) I also live in a real world where I manage plenty of people, have children and so many years of work that a lot of patronising language is tiring. This has nothing to do with my ego - just that it doe snot really help. Leaving a comment does, though. The other thing is that there are SE communities that are extremely welcoming (LaTeX for instance), and others frankly toxic where questions that are just this: questions - create drama. But this is life I guess.

Comment: Maybe someday SO will get rid of downvotes.  They don't contribute to the quality of the site because a downvote is not necessarily tied to the quality of the question.  Upvotes are truly the only vote about quality...nobody upvotes out of spite :)  I'm writing this as a comment because any post on meta about eliminating downvotes is itself downvoted into oblivion.  People like having an outlet for their aggression I guess.

Comment: @Paul maybe someday we will get rid of *all* the votes. Please, upvotes are not about quality, they are about *popularity*. Just like votes in real life - we did not invent anything new. Something of questionable quality can be voted up easily (go check the JS and Python tags if you skipped them for a while), and vice versa is true about voting down, I have to admit.

Comment: @OlegValter I guess I've been upvoting wrong because I upvote questions (and answers) I find useful.  I have to retract my previous statement that "nobody upvotes out of spite" because I realized I do that. When I see a new user's question downvoted without any comments explaining why I may upvote to counter the unexplained downvotes (unless the question is egregiously bad).  Getting rid of all the votes is an interesting idea. I would support that on questions and allow upvotes only on answers.

Comment: I haven't noticed any additional scrutiny with my rep. If I ask a shite question then the community lets me know just as vehemently now as it did when I joined 8 years ago. Hopefully this doesn't trigger the "Meta Effect", dum dumm dummmmm!

Comment: @Paul "They don't contribute to the quality of the site because a downvote is not necessarily tied to the quality of the question. Upvotes are truly the only vote about quality...nobody upvotes out of spite :)" Very valid opinion. Still I would disagree. An Upvote not given is the same as a Downvote for the score (repwise an Upvote not given is even the same as five Downvotes). They are both strongly related, only people don't like being criticized, even if it would help them. They rather don't want to hear anything at all.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "I haven't noticed any additional scrutiny..." Business idea: paid consulting by high rep (>20k) users that go over ones contributions and give feedback on how to improve (and vote on what they see along the way). Or as long as there aren't too many such inquiries, you could just ask for it on Meta. :)

Comment: @Trilarion A downvote without explanation is not criticism and is not helpful.  It's like getting a math test back with only a grade and no markings.  How does one know where to improve?  Maybe the downvote button should be part of the comment process; one can only downvote when leaving a comment.

Comment: @Paul Maybe read this one :) [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: @Scratte Thank you for the link. I understand the reasoning behind downvotes but have always disagreed with it.  From the accepted answer, "first and foremost...[downvotes] are a way of communicating to future readers that a question or answer is not interesting or useful".  I would change this to read, "Not upvoting is a way of communicating to future readers that a question or answer is not interesting or useful" or conversely, "upvoting is the way to communicate to future readers that a question or answer is interesting or useful."  We shall agree to disagree :)

Comment: @Paul "A downvote without explanation is not criticism and is not helpful." I agree that the explanation is not very explicit and we could probably start to vote on aspects, but I think that the whole argumentation would be the same for upvotes (no explanation, not helpful). In particular I think that downvotes and upvotes not given are practically the same. If there are two answers and your answer has score 0 and the other answer has score 1 then the other answer is better than yours or yours is worse than the other. There is a reason why some answers aren't upvoted as much as others.

Comment: My primary suspicion was that you were posting questions mainly to answer them yourself and gain reputation. But I checked thoroughly, and found this not really being the case (even the answers for the questions you posted yourself were some hours later). So I have no idea indeed.

Comment: @Victor-ReinstateMonica: the case where I answer my own questions are two fold: either I finished the question and then realized that I finally know the answer so I immediately post an answer. This is also the case where i find (through the suggestions) that a question is a duplicate: I post it, then flag as duplicate and finalize the duplicate. The other case is when i found the answer after some hours and i get back to post it so it is useful for others.

Comment: @Victor-ReinstateMonica (cont'd) As a side note - I find it strange rep is always mentioned - some  people genuinely do not care. In my case I like to be able to edit questions and answers to either reformat or to add some links (but this is only 1 or 2k, I do not remember)

Comment: "so it is useful for others." That's actually a reason for voting. It might be that people think that the contributions are too special to be very useful.

Comment: @WoJ it might be personal (most probably is), but I am _personally_ more offended by people who predominantly answer their own questions (_even if I'd seldom downvote them for this_) in an instant than either any supposed _offensiveness_ or _lack of utility_ - both being something that I could not always find _objective_.
(But then again, AFAIR I've only ever asked a single question, and that was here on Meta, it was about _downvoting_, and it received a balance of -16 to this day, so YMMV :D)

Answer (score 66):

There is no extra scrutiny at any level. You got downvotes due to several factors:

- Your recent questions aren't very interesting
- Asking questions is not an easy task; it's not unusual to receive downvotes for a question
- Your recent questions were asked in Go, which is a very thoroughly moderated tag. There are a number of users who watch new questions
- A post on meta raised awareness of your question. This is called a Meta-effect

Downvotes are nothing to worry about, especially with your reputation. You won't get banned any time soon. I know this from experience. Many of my questions have more downvotes than upvotes.

**Do not create a new account if this one gets banned.** This is not permitted and it will only get both accounts suspended.

Comment: you got more downvotes, because you scold user in php a lot

Comment: @nbk Not on my questions. But I agree many of these downvotes are out of spite. Some people are very petty.

Comment: Worth noting that the "meta-effect" does not contain itself to the question in question, but attracts all sorts of attention from people who will now trawl through the user's profile to try to gauge whether the question in question is an isolated case or whether the user may have a history of whatever it is that's being discussed on meta, etc. Votes follow clicks.

Comment: "Do not create a new account if this one gets banned. This is not permitted and it will only get both accounts suspended." How can anyone ever know the same user is behind two accounts? It seems like an unenforcable rule.

Comment: Posting comments on meta is one way.

Comment: @nbk everyone who isn't a quiet drive-by downvoter will get revenge votes. I think it's more valuable to let someone know why you downvoted their question in the hope they can learn something from it.

Comment: @miken32 i have a lot of revenge votes on my answers and my questions, as i said here often that is normal life in SO, it stopped somewhat since i don't review any more, but as i  comment on "bad questions" i still get them occasionally. I bmost parts the cloase vpotes aöready tell you what went wrong, some questions seems salvageable, so i comment, but besides [mre] and  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  i can't give them any help

Answer (score 42):

No, it's probably a fluke.  But this is an ***overreaction***...

> Worst case I will leave this account on the side (use it for the other SE) and start a new one but it is really a pity.

You can be upvoted and downvoted.  It happens.  It's not *worth* junking your current near-20K+ rep account to start a new one because some people might find your questions or answers not as useful as others, and because the ratio is always 10 rep gained versus 2 rep lost, you'd need a whole ***lot*** of users downvoting you legitimately to justify such a move.

Comment: I was only worried about the block - the ego/rep or whatever part is not an issue at all. Glad to see that I can continue to participate :)

Comment: @WoJ Iirc, you'll get a warning message if the downvotes are actually becoming relevant to your block score. If you haven't seen anything, you're far from being blocked.

Comment: Also, to be clear, if you started a new account *to evade a question block* that would be not allowed, and get you in more hot water...

Comment: Lmao, do people really react like this over their SO rep? SO rep is relatively meaningless honestly.

Comment: @WalterMonecke you'd be surprised :) SE employs a real-world psychological trick preying on us being conditioned the bigger amount something is the better (think money). DVs are intentionally painted red and deduce rep, and UVs green and add. This keeps people going (and yes, you *personally* don't care about it but it doesn't mean others don't) through the positive and negative feedback loops. It is no surprise people act strongly for being dv'ed (you can't explain to them that the votes are on content as reason can't invalidate feelings [we'd live in a better world should this be the case])

Comment: @OlegValter Well, I feel sad for whoever takes their SO rep to the point of feeling hurt when they get downvoted.

Comment: @WalterMonecke me too - but that's humans for you. I don't know if you used Meta in read mode, but we get a cry for "unfair" voting about once a week, maybe more. It's not that hard to feel hurt when you see a red negative number deducing something from your "virtual capital" - just how this conditioning works, unfortunately.

Comment: @OlegValter Or to put it briefly -- Fake internet points provide real endorphins :)

Answer (score 14):

As others have already said: No, we don't single-out users at a particular rep threshold and double-check their questions.

That having been said, there *is* something that you could do: SO strives to be a repository of great questions and answers for the reference of future readers.  At 20k rep, you now have *much more* experience in how to write a great question than when you started. There's nothing wrong with

- going back to your old questions,
- considering if they can be improved in a way that will benefit future readers (without invalidating existing answers) and
- editing them.

Significant edits will also bump them to the front page, so they will be re-read by the community and might even earn you some upvotes. (That also means that touching unsalvageable bad old questions might be risky - better leave those alone.)

Answer (score -35):

Yes. Posts are discriminated by author. High rep invites both more scrutiny from tag experts, and more benefit of doubt from others. The effect also varies across networks (and, for SO, tags), greater for smaller ones.

Though not much special about 20k, just high rep.

**Edit**: in Stack Exchanges's favor I'll point that it's the *least* biased platform I know. Aeons ahead of Twitter etc. But it has enough to not skirt under the rug.

Comment: _Posts are discriminated by author._ ---> Citation needed.

Comment: This is a vast over-simplification / generalization.  It's probably true that if a question seems "bad" / overly simplistic, but the user has a lot of rep, people will read it more carefully to see if there's actually an interesting question that they're missing.  As for holding a high-rep user to higher standards of quality since "they should know better"?  Well maybe, at least in terms of basic formatting.  But that's not a problem for the querent's questions.

Comment: Experienced users do sometimes ask novice questions about a thing they're just learning, and yeah sometimes those are too obvious, but I don't think we hold them to a higher standard than new users for that.  Expecting SO to spoon-feed you a language tutorial as you ask a stream of questions will get you downvotes in any tag, no matter who you are.  (Not saying WoJ's questions are like that; I'm thinking of other cases I've seen in tags I follow.)  Anyway, if you describe some of those nuances, this could be an ok answer, but as-is doesn't explain the downvotes.

Comment: This isn't even *remotely* true. The vast majority of people, myself included, do not even take a cursory glance at the user card before deciding whether to upvote or downvote a post. All that's required is to, you know, *read the post*.

Comment: @CodyGray for me it is generally painfully easy to see and recognize posts by the same author (for cases where details/research actually posted)... People rarely succeed in radically changing the style they write in and if one asks multiple questions in a relatively narrow area (like C# or Python) you'd know in a second that the post you are looking at is by the author of questionable questions  you've seen in the past. At that point you know that you can't vote (as it would be targeted voting) and in my case I just skip post altogether...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: If you read the question enough to decide that you think *the question* is bad, after you make an effort to set aside your bias based on that user's previous question, you can still downvote.  (Unless it's been more than a couple questions from the same user in the same day, in which automated scripts might roll back your votes.)  You're right that you can't (or shouldn't) *just* look at the first sentence, then the username, and roll your eyes and say "oh, this guy again" and downvote.

Comment: @10Rep Posts are not discriminated by author. ---> Citation needed as well. Absence of evidence is not evidence for the opposite. We don't know. Posts may be discriminated by author. The prominent display of the author's rep enables the effect at least.

Comment: @CodyGray "This isn't even remotely true." I think this statement is over-confident. Without hard statistical data I would prefer something more like "we don't know" or "quality of content will probably prevail in the end". For example I remember this case where a highly voted wrong answer kept on getting upvotes for no good reason except it being first in the sorting order and having a high score. Even selection criteria (which post to look at) might play a role. Maybe more investigation (show fake rep for some time and compare) is needed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: It's also a bit questionable to downvote a new question because they missed the point of previous answers to their previous question about the same overall task. But if the new question could be valid on its own, you do still have the option of voting for "lack of research effort", if it's not a duplicate.  I'd certainly consider carefully reading the answers to their own previous question as an expected part of the research effort!  (I'm mostly thinking of a case where someone decides they want to learn assembly language and asks a bunch of similar questions.)

Comment: @Trilarion: This meta question is about *question* voting, isn't it?  Herd mentality upvoting already-upvoted answers is a very well known phenomenon.  (Looks like some effort went into it, and some other people already checked it was good and upvoted, so it must be good and I'll upvote too...)  But SO voters are much more skeptical of questions, and don't tend to go along with the herd on question upvotes.  (Except on questions that attracted good canonical answers. I used to upvote questions based on them having attracted good answers, but I don't anymore.)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon You've gotten a lot of downvotes on this answer, but I can't help but wonder if you're right. It would be interesting to run an experiment where you show users a question and artificially change the question author's reputation to 1 or an arbitrary large number. I would fall over dead if there weren't at least a small effect. I suspect the direction of the effect would vary by user personality.

Comment: @IanCampbell They won't admit it. Unfortunately such an experiment is the only way to prove my point - and I've gathered enough data from personal observation to back my answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Optimism helps. It also insults those afflicted when wrong. People are biased. Studies have shown same experts give different verdicts on same matters when asked on different times of day. Buuut we have egos to look after.

Comment: @Trilarion If I make a claim, and I want people to believe this claim, then I should provide some evidence. If I don't provide any evidence then people will believe that what I said is wrong, no? From what I know, nobody downvotes high rep users (in fact, for me, it used to be the opposite. I would downvote a post and then see that it's a high rep user and then consider undoing my downvote). That's why I said citation needed. That being said, you do have a point.

Comment: @10Rep Full agreement. I would also like to see evidence of this. Just wanted to point out that there is not much evidence to the contrary either. Basically a lot of what is said on meta is personal experience which can vary or is speculation. If I would need evidence for everything that is said I would have to write "citation needed" a couple of times per post.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - *"I've gathered enough data from personal observation to back my answer"* - Then you should present the data for people to look at ... and explain your methodology for gathering it.

Comment: @StephenC A fifth of voters agree with me. There's your data.

Comment: Surely gathered data, like a study, is superior to a mere claim. But where's the counter-data? Then I'm  equal with opposition. And rejection on this alone is cheap - it burdens with a task an individual clearly cannot pull off reasonably.

Comment: I have a hard time even understanding what this answer is supposed to mean.