# Make Rollbacks more intuitive for <2k

Tags: feature-request, design, suggested-edits, rollbacks

[zcoop98](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11047824/zcoop98) [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408342/11573842) *'[How do you rollback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271934/11573842)'* a few minutes ago with an answer that shows how <2k rep users can suggest an edit. To quote that answer:

> Using the "Rev" dropdown, simply select the revision of the previous
> edit which you desire to roll back to, they'll all be listed in this
> menu:
>
> [image: Location of rev dropdown on edit page]

**I never know that this was an option!**

When I was <2k I would copy the text from the revision history and paste it over the current text and re-format it to match the previous rev. Or I would [request higher-rep members to roll back on my behalf](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=roll+back+please&user=11573842&room=41570)...

It would have been a lot more convenient to have a clear button to rollback posts (like I do now). How about something like this for <2k users?:

> [image]

Comment: This would be pretty nice. I (and Sabito) participate in Charcoal, where we catch a lot of vandalism across the network. Naturally, you can't expect us to have full edit privileges everywhere. On some sites, finding a moderator or >2k user to help roll the edit back within a reasonable timeframe is rare, so having this be easily accessible would be a blessing.

Comment: In general the idea seems nice. Two problems I can already imagine: 1. (minor) We should still have someway to add a summary explaining *why* the rollback is necessary for reviewers. 2. Considering vandalism, we want to revert it fast. By proposing a rollback you now need two more people to approve it instead of one to do it themselves (which might be the reason why rollbacks are not easy to begin with)

Comment: @Tomerikoo 1. I honestly feel like rollback comments should be a thing like edit comments are... I don't like [barging into an ongoing conversation to tell someone why I rolled back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408255/is-there-some-kind-of-special-scrutiny-near-20k#comment847968_408255). 2. True, but I feel like a lot of <2k won't even suggest an edit if they find vandalism and don't know how to roll back... I was asking in a chat room, not everyone will...

Comment: o_O I never knew this was even an option when I was under 2K. Good proposal - count one more supporting vote. Although, as usual, I doubt anything will be done in less than 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I didn't realize this was so underutilized! I haven't used the feature on many occasions, but it dawned on me that I hadn't seen it documented anywhere, hence the answer.

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 I think I was misunderstood. Regarding 1, I meant that when you edit (no matter the rep) you have an option to write a summary of what's the purpose of the edit. For <2k that's mandatory to help reviewers. When rollingback, there is no option for such summary. What I meant is that for <2k a rollback is an edit like any other which will get to review. Part of that means making it possible to write a summary (why was the rollback necessary) to help reviewers. Regarding 2, I agree that it might not be so important for *most* cases

Comment: Most of the time, we don't want sub-2k to do rollbacks.

Comment: 2k should still be able to rollback to a previous revision, though. When I was under 2k I had no idea what a rollback even was! And like @Spevacus said, if I'm on another site where I have less than 2k and I need to rollback vandalism, it's helpful to have a easy way to do it. (I also participate in charcoal).

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes there is rollback comment functionality that is obscurely documented & obscurely done. You click edit (!) on the version you want to roll back to & only edit the edit summary. This causes a rollback (!) with your text added (!) to the default rollback edit summary text that the version is a rollback.