# Is there a list of comment expansion links?

Tags: support

This is probably a duplicate as I'm all but certain I'm not the first person to ask this question, but I don't know the right term to search for. Feel free to close as a dupe if necessary.

When I comment on the infamous "begging for code" questions I use `[mcve]` in the comment which expands into a link to the definition of a "Minimal, Reproduceable Example (I'm aware the shorthand used there is from the older "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example" text). But I'm not sure what other expansions are possible, if there are any. Is there a list of these anywhere?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/397219)

Comment: [mre]  works on So DBA ...., but it doesn't help at all so add also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query but this also doesn't help always